# Fibonacci series in dynamic programming in python

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

```
# Program 1
fibSeries = {}
def fib(n):    
    a,b = 1,1
    for i in range(1,n+1):        
        if i <= 2: 
            f = 1
        else: 
            f = a + b
            a = b
            b = f
        fibSeries[i] = f
    return f

print (fib(number))
print (fibSeries)

# Program 2
fibSeries={}
def fib(n):
    for k in range(1,n+1):
        if k <= 2: f = 1
        else: f = fib(k-1) + fib(k-2)
        fibSeries[k] = f
    return f

print(fib(number))
print(fibSeries)
```

I have started dynamic programming and my first program is to find Fibonacci series. I have written the above two programs. My first question is which among these programs comes under dynamic programming? Which among these two programs is a better one? Is there a better way than program 1 to find the nth Fibonacci number faster? Is program 2 better than recursion? And how to find the number of times the function is called in program 2?

Comment: Too many questions spoil the question!

Comment: Look at the second answer. Anything that is either memoized or tabulated (using tables to store memory) is DP.

Comment: Then what type is program 1? Because I find program 1 to be faster than program 2.